# Run benchmark fail test in pallet-evm

Tags: pallet, benchmarking, frontier

`test_benchmarks` fail

Repo: `https://github.com/paritytech/frontier`

Command: `cargo t -p pallet-evm --features runtime-benchmarks`

Issue:

```
failures:

---- benchmarking::benchmark_tests::test_benchmarks stdout ----
failing benchmark tests:
thread 'benchmarking::benchmark_tests::test_benchmarks' panicked at 'create() failed', frame/evm/src/benchmarking.rs:96:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
runner_execute: Any { .. }
thread 'benchmarking::benchmark_tests::test_benchmarks' panicked at 'assertion failed: !anything_failed', frame/evm/src/benchmarking.rs:149:1
```

Comment: ACK the test is indeed failing since the CI seems to be misconfigured. I will try to fix it, thanks! If you discover something like this the next time please directly open an issue here https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/issues/new/choose, thanks.